# How to list the names of all the branches from a repository using GitHttpClient (API)

Tags: c#, git, rest

I tried GitHttpClient.GetBranchesAsync(ProjectName, RepositoryId) but this only returns Count i.e. Number of branches or Capacity

Comment: Have you looked at the docs? (i have never used this library) though have you tried `GetBranchRefsAsync` just a guess

Comment: I tried it shows the same properties, I believe BranchRefAsync would be for a single branch, I maybe be wrong

Comment: GetBranchesAsync works fine it returns a list hence count and capacity were the only properties working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[That method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.sourcecontrol.webapi.githttpclientbase.getbranchesasync?view=azure-devops-dotnet#Microsoft_TeamFoundation_SourceControl_WebApi_GitHttpClientBase_GetBranchesAsync_System_String_System_String_Microsoft_TeamFoundation_SourceControl_WebApi_GitVersionDescriptor_System_Object_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) returns `List<GitBranchStats>`, so you should have all the information you need. It's just a simple list. Iterate through it and inspect the items to find the info you need.